# How to Call command prompt from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, windows, batch-file, cmd

this my first question on stackoverflow.I am developing asp.net web application,in one web form i want to call cmd.exe from javascript , after clicking on the button on server side
here is my code snippet

```
function onRec(){
try{
var commandtoRun = "c:\\WINDOWS/system32/cmd.exe";
var commandParms = "dir"; 
alert("start recording   ");
var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, commandParms, "", "open", "1");
}
catch(err)
{
 alert(err.message):
}
}
<input type="button"  name="Record" value="Record" onclick="OnRecStart();" />
```

this code is not calling the cmd.exe ,i also tried

```
string filepath= Server.MapPath("../VideoStreaming/Record.bat"); 
ProcessStartInfo oProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filepath);
oProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "dir";
oProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process oProcess = Process.Start(oProcessStartInfo);
oProcess.Start();
```

the above code is  working fine but when i published it and trying to running from IIS it is not working ,why it is not working i m not understanding please help me...
is there any browser security issue..?please give me the suggestion how can i do that .
thanks in advance.

Comment: "`is there any browser security issue..?`" Yes, there are many security issues, why you shouldn't even try this. Via command line you're capable to do almost anything within user's machine...

Comment: @Teemu:thanks for your suggestion,i didnt work on command line till now,i will try by using command line....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done due to security issues

Comment: There is nothing that you have to solve. If you are able to run cmd from javascript. It is quite easy to hack a computer. Therefor any browser will not let you run any command prompt scripts or even have access to the computer. What are you trying to do? And why do you have to use the command prompt from javascript?

Comment: i want to record a network stream by using ip camera for which i am using [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) in ffmpeg we have to pass command to record network stream,i passed command successfully on local machine but when i published it will not call cmd.exe ,please tell me how hack computer ....thanks

Comment: why don't you just create a desktop application? or record on the server itself? and push the video from the server to the webpage if you need to see it.